# Default english stemming in SOLR

Tags: solr, stemming

I'm trying to do simple english words stemming in SOLR, but for some reason I'm not successful.

my xml doc looks like this:

```
<add><doc>
  <str name="id">1</str>
  <str name="name">walked</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="id">2</str>
  <str name="name">walking</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="id">3</str>
  <str name="name">walks</str>
</doc>
</add>
```

in schema XML I change name type to "text_en"

```
<field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I don't change anything else and I think it should work (I tried everything: creating new fields and new fieldTypes for them according to various tutorials and so on, but something goes wrong and I don't know what)

One more point if I try to anlyse these words in analysis section in SOLR
(`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis`) 
It works fine.

For example:

Field Value(index) and Field Value(query) I input value: walking. Text field in PorterStemFilter section equals "walk" as I wish.

But when I do query walking in query section it matches **0 values**! I want it to match all values (walking, walked, walks)
query url: `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*walking*&wt=json&indent=true`

**EDIT**

P.S. I reindexed this many times, it can't be a problem.

**EDIT #2**

Thank you very much. Now everything is clear. I will explain what I undestood today, maybe it will be useful for someone.

If your url is like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=walking&wt=json&indent=true
```

You are using field: "text" (default field is text), because there isn't specified field in query.

```
 <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

If you want to stem specific field not "text", you have to specify it in url. For example field "name":

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=name:walking&wt=json&indent=true
```

one more point not to forget. field property "indexed" which you want to stem must be set to "true".
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't look right, try to query it like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=name:walking&wt=json&indent=true
```